# TensorFlow 2.0 TFLite Quantized export with UINT8 weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, convolution, quantization

In the previous TensorFlow version I used (1.9) I was able to quantize my network with UINT8 weights stored in the Conv2D operation inputs.  Now with TensorFlow 2.0 using a Keras model, post-training quantization gives me INT8 weights with seemingly no option for unsigned weights.  Is it not possible to control the sign on the weights in Conv layers with TF 2.0?

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
def representative_dataset_gen():
  for _ in range(num_calibration_steps):
    # Get sample input data as a numpy array in a method of your choosing.
    yield [input]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
# there is no such tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_UINT8
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8  # or tf.int8 ( note this has zero effect on the tensors produced for Conv2D operations -- all of which include signed int8 unless you were to output the model as float16/32 )
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8  # or tf.int8
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
```

Answer (score 1):

The most recent version of TensorFlow (2.5) utilizes a more robust quantization scheme on the Convolutional networks where each filter depth maps to different quantization levels.  As of current there is not a way to utilize the prior method.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar need to quantize my model to UINT8 , can you share how to do this in tensorflow 1.9 ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this mean that UINT8 quantization is not supported by TF 2.x?

Comment: @ai2ys From what I can tell, yes. The signed int8 methods are the way forward and I can report it does definitely improve performance in its current implementation, if that helps.

Comment: @Kalen I am asking specifically for the uint8 support, because of a hardware only supporting uint8 operations. I was hoping for using TF for the quantization task instead of the vendor tool.

Comment: @ai2ys As far as I can work out, the tf2x scripts involved in the export had zero functionality when giving it uint8 as params.  I tried every permutation available at the time to no avail.  I would recommend using the earlier version.